# MarkerOnClick data are null

Tags: android, google-maps

### **I am setting marker as follows** and I am able to see the marker on the map

```
 if (googleMap != null && mapFragment != null && googleMap.getProjection() != null) {
                                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                            Double.parseDouble(storesWithDistance.getLatitude() + ""), Double.parseDouble(storesWithDistance.getLongitude() + "")
                                    )).title(storesWithDistance.getStoreName() + "").snippet(i + ""));
                                }
```

---

```
`marker.getTitle()` is returning `null` ..... Why is it happening ?
```

---

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        try {
            if (googleMap != null && mapFragment != null && googleMap.getProjection() != null) {

                String title = marker.getTitle();
                String snippet = marker.getSnippet();

                Log.d("","");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

did you implemented the interface **GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener** ?
did you add this line ? :

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
```

what if you try to put your `String title = marker.getTitle();` out of **try..catch** block and test it with Log.d()?

Comment: I have the onclick listener, just the data is not getting stored in marker ....but markers are visible in map

Comment: then try to make **mMarker** as a global class variable then assign it like this:                      
`mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                            Double.parseDouble(storesWithDistance.getLatitude() + ""), Double.parseDouble(storesWithDistance.getLongitude() + "")
                                    )).title(storesWithDistance.getStoreName() + "").snippet(i + ""));`

Comment: But fina;lly where are you adding *mMarker =* in teh end its not used anywhere right ? ... Can you explain

Comment: then , mMaker will have a new instance for the visual added Maker, so like that you will be able to get all its attributs .. but tell me it worked for you ?

Comment: Nop ... Finally I did a workaround by using a lat/long and getting values from collection ...its a wiered issue ...[+1] for your inputs

Comment: Thank you sir, 
but if you want can you copy/past all of your code here if this will not bother you? because I implemented your code in my PC and it worked for me, so maybe you have another issue that blocks your marker click event or passing the exact data .
Using collection for your code is not really a nice solution ..